# Trying to call 2 JS files but only 1 works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page that is calling 2 JS files (2 images sliders on different parts of 1 page on a website with 2 different sets of images). My problem is only 1 slider is working while the other does not. Are you not allowed to call 2 different JS files on 1 HTML doc? Another weird thing is, I separated the 2 image sliders into 2 different HTML docs and called for their respective JS file and they both worked, but not when they are on the same page. Sorry I am new to all of this.

HTML

```
<video src="./pics/acecs2.mp4" muted loop autoplay controls></video>


      </section>
      <div class="bowl-container">
      <div class="slider-wrap">
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider-item">
            <div class="img-div"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <section class="showcase2">


      <video src="./pics/ace3.mp4" muted loop autoplay controls></video>


    </section>
    <div class="bowl-container2">
    <div class="slider-wrap2">
      <div class="slider2">
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item2">
          <div class="img-div2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="app2.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
let sliderWrap = document.querySelector('.slider-wrap');
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let clonesWidth;
let sliderWidth;
let clones = [];
let scrollPos = 1
let sliderHover = false;
let req;1
let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item')];
let images = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img-div')];


images.forEach((image, idx) => {
    image.style.backgroundImage = `url(./pics2/${idx+1}.jpg)`
})

items.forEach(item => {
    let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add('clone');
    slider.appendChild(clone);
    clones.push(clone);
})

sliderWrap.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{
    sliderHover = true;
})

sliderWrap.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
    sliderHover = false;
})

function getClonesWidth(){
    let width = 0;
    clones.forEach(clone => {
        width += clone.offsetWidth;
    })
    return width;
}


function scrollUpdate(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 760){
        sliderWrap.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        if(!sliderHover){
            scrollPos -= .4
        }

        if(clonesWidth + scrollPos >= sliderWidth){
            
            scrollPos = 1;
        }else if(scrollPos <= 0){
            
            scrollPos = sliderWidth - clonesWidth - 1
        }
        slider.style.transform = `translateX(${-scrollPos}px)`

        req = requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate)
    }else{
        sliderWrap.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }

}


function onLoad(){

    calaculateDimensions()
    scrollPos = 1;
    scrollUpdate();
}

function calaculateDimensions(){

    sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    clonesWidth = getClonesWidth();
}

onLoad();
```

app2.js

```
let sliderWrap2 = document.querySelector('.slider-wrap2');
let slider2 = document.querySelector('.slider2');
let clonesWidth2;
let sliderWidth2;
let clones2 = [];
let scrollPos2 =1
let sliderHover2 = false;
let req2; // request animation frame reference
let items2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider-item2')];
let images2 = [...document.querySelectorAll('.img-div2')];


images2.forEach((image, idx) => {
    image.style.backgroundImage = `url(./pics3/${idx+1}.jpg)`
})

items2.forEach(item => {
    let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add('clone');
    slider2.appendChild(clone);
    clones2.push(clone);
})

sliderWrap2.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{
    sliderHover2 = true;
})

sliderWrap2.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>{
    sliderHover2 = false;
})

function getClonesWidth(){
    let width = 0;
    clones2.forEach(clone => {
        width += clone.offsetWidth;
    })
    return width;
}


function scrollUpdate(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 760){
        sliderWrap2.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        if(!sliderHover2){
            scrollPos2 -= .15
        }

        if(clonesWidth2 + scrollPos2 >= sliderWidth2){
            
            scrollPos2 = 1;
        }else if(scrollPos2 <= 0){
            
            scrollPos2 = sliderWidth2 - clonesWidth2 - 1
        }
        slider2.style.transform = `translateX(${-scrollPos2}px)`

        req2 = requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate)
    }else{
        sliderWrap2.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    }

}


function onLoad(){

    calaculateDimensions()
    scrollPos2 = 1;
    scrollUpdate();
}

function calaculateDimensions(){

    sliderWidth2 = slider2.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    clonesWidth2 = getClonesWidth();
}

onLoad()
```

Comment: Post the JavaScript and HTML of each here as text please.

Comment: Please add your code, where you are getting this problem.

Comment: I'm all but certain the JS that runs the slider is not written to handle more than a single slider on a page at once. Yes you can absolutely have more than one JS file loaded on a single webpage at a time, but depending on how the slider JS is coded, it could be looking for the first slider element, using IDs, or any number of other methods which can only handle a single slider on the page. You'll have to post the JS and HTML if you want a definitive answer.

Comment: Just added the code.

Comment: @turntlane what do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error message of some sort?

Comment: @EKW only the 2nd image slider actually "slides". The first slider doesn't "slide" it only displays the box with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scope your functions with the 2 suffix as well. An alternative is to add the `type="module"` attribute. If you do that, then you won't need any 2 suffixes except as the html is concerned

Comment: where do I add type="module"?

Comment: Add it to script so <script type="module> instead of <script>

Comment: it worked!! thank you so much. Just looked it up and now I understand why that worked. I appreciate it!

Comment: Np, Could you please accept/upvote my answer if it answered your question? Thanks

Comment: not able to upvote yet but accepted the answer. thanks again!

Comment: Thank you also just want to note that this is not the prefered way of having multiple sliders you would want to use querySelectorAll on the container and loop through them all